# Label transformation vs Methods in Imblanced Regression for Imbalanced Regression tasks

Tags: regression

I've seen some papers discussing the imbalanced regression recently and was wondering what's the benefit of this line of approaches compared to conventional data transformations (e.g., Square-root, Log transform or Box-cox)?

### Papers in Imbalanced Regression

- Delving into Deep Imbalanced Regression, Yang et al., ICML-21
- Balanced MSE for Imbalanced Visual Regression, Ren et al., CVPR-22
- RankSim: Ranking Similarity Regularization for Imb Reg, Gong et al., ICML-22